# ASP.NET route segments of path

Tags: c#, asp.net

For example:

```
localhost:3000/en/guide/...
```

I've written a condition:

```
var path = context.UrlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Path;
if (path.StartsWithSegments($"/{context.Culture}/guide"))
```

However, there can be case when:

```
localhost:3000/en/some-page/guide/...
```

I tried:

```
else if (path.StartsWithSegments($"/{context.Culture}/meeting-rooms") ||
        (path.StartsWithSegments($"/{context.Culture}") && path.Value.Equals("guide")))
```

This code does not work correctly in this case, it should have been checking if there is some segment are equals to "guide". So, have be like

```
path.Segments.Any("guide")
```

but the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString` does not contain such a property `Segments`.

Comment: Why are you writing this code? Where is it? It feels like you don't understand asp.net routing and link generation. Are you attempting something like https://andrewlock.net/applying-the-routedatarequest-cultureprovider-globally-with-middleware-as-filters/ ?